# Add a row using linq or sql in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I am developing an application, and as one of the steps, I need to have a set of information backed up to an SQL database.

I don't have any experience using SQL, and was hoping I could find a simple command that would just add a row with the information i'd needed... But I don't understand much of the information I've found for it. I've even had issues just using the snippet provided within Visual Studio.

I tried using the snippet for adding a row, and here's the code that's produced.

The reference to RDataSet.ArchivedIncidentsDataTable keeps giving me an error message telling me "object reference to non-shared object requires an object reference", which to me, is one of the least helpful error messages you could possibly receive. I don't understand what it means, or what I need to do in order to fix it.
Here is the code that I have, which is basically just the snippet that's provided:

```
    Private Sub Save_SQLBackup_Info()
        Dim newRow = CType(RDataSet.ArchivedIncidentsDataTable.NewRow(), RDataSet.ArchivedIncidentsRow)
    newRow.CustomerID = "A124"
    newRow.CompanyName = "Acme"
    RDataSet.ArchivedIncidentsDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow)

End Sub
```

I'm not sure how filling in the fields for this small amount of code produced an error.

Also, after this segment of code is run, don't I have to run a command to update the database? The guides I'd been following online all referenced something like that, but I didn't understand the other parts of them.

I'm sure the problem i'm having is a matter of "You didn't declare X.", however I don't know much about SQL... If that's even what I'm using. 
I would appreciate some guidance.
All I need to do is add a row to the database using a few fields from the form.

I have an online SQL server linked as a data object, and the dataset is titled RDataSet , the data table is titled ArchivedIncidentsDataTable.
The few guides I've found online reference different parts, like data adapters, that I don't have, and / or don't reference how they got to that part... I'm completely lost.

Is there any sort of one-line command I can run that will just shoot the information I'd like added to a row into this database? I don't understand why it has to be this complicated...

EDIT: 
One of the answers was to drag an instance of the dataset onto the form.
After doing this, and trying to reference it, I'm now getting an error message telling me :

```
"Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.
```

This message appears under the autocorrect options, and gives me the option to replace the dataset I added to the form, RDataSet1, with RDataset.

When hovering over the code "RDataSet1.ArchivedIncidentsDataTable.NewRow()", I still see the error message "Object Reference requires an object reference".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've seperated a few of the sentences into paragraph format now so that they would be easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message

> object reference to non-shared object requires an object reference

means you're trying to access a member of a class like it's a shared member, but it's not, so you need an actually instance of that class (an object reference).

If you're using `WinForms`, you can just drag a `RDataSet` onto your `Form`, and it should generate a field in your `Form` called `RDataSet1` or something like that (I asumme you used the DataSet Designer of Visual Studio).

Then use `RDataSet1` (the object reference) instead of `RDataSet` (the type).

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I hadn't done that, and so I found the RDataSet option under my toolbox and dragged it into the form.

I'm still getting the error message now (Edited main post), however now I'm also seeing an auto-correct option to replace RDataSet1 with RDataSet.

Comment: Also, thank you **very much** for explaining the difference between RDataSet1 being the object reference, and RDataSet being the type. That makes a lot of sense to me now.